# Image segmentation - Object recognition

Tags: opencv, image-recognition

So this is my idea : I have a photo of a supermarket shelf ([Shelf example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXjbE.jpg))
and I would like to have it "categorized" by objects or "same-object-sets", something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Rbp.jpg) (but on the whole picture)
Do you have any ideas of how this could be done, using a Visual Recognition API or something like OpenCV maybe ?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can give a look to template matching with opencv as shown [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/using-opencv-python-and-template-matching-to-play-wheres-waldo/) or [here for a multiscale approach](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/). 

 For some theory about how it's done you can look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html).

Comment: Thanks ! I will try this and let you know if it worked